# "del /f /s /q" doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have a Win10 script that tries to delete ...\User*\AppData\Local* from my backups. It uses `del /f /s /q`, but it doesn't seem to always work. The command runs, but nothing gets deleted.

For example, below shows what happens when I try to manually delete the folder "Apps" - first I try with `del /f /s /q`, then with `rmdir /s /q`. Neither works - the folder remains.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I delete these folder trees?

```
f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local>dir
 Volume in drive F is Backup 1 TB
 Volume Serial Number is 427B-96E5

 Directory of f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local

09/27/2017  04:23 PM    <DIR>          .
09/27/2017  04:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/10/2016  02:10 PM    <DIR>          3Dconnexion
06/11/2016  06:06 PM    <DIR>          ActiveSync
09/27/2017  02:00 AM    <DIR>          Adobe
08/05/2016  04:37 PM    <DIR>          Amazon
11/10/2014  04:53 PM    <DIR>          Apple
11/10/2014  04:54 PM    <DIR>          Apple Computer
09/27/2017  04:16 PM    <DIR>          Apps
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  457,199,636,480 bytes free

f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local>del /f /s /q Apps

f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local>dir
 Volume in drive F is Backup 1 TB
 Volume Serial Number is 427B-96E5

 Directory of f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local

09/27/2017  04:23 PM    <DIR>          .
09/27/2017  04:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/10/2016  02:10 PM    <DIR>          3Dconnexion
06/11/2016  06:06 PM    <DIR>          ActiveSync
09/27/2017  02:00 AM    <DIR>          Adobe
08/05/2016  04:37 PM    <DIR>          Amazon
11/10/2014  04:53 PM    <DIR>          Apple
11/10/2014  04:54 PM    <DIR>          Apple Computer
09/27/2017  04:16 PM    <DIR>          Apps
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  457,199,636,480 bytes free

f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local>rmdir /s /q Apps
The directory is not empty.

f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local>dir
 Volume in drive F is Backup 1 TB
 Volume Serial Number is 427B-96E5

 Directory of f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local

09/27/2017  04:23 PM    <DIR>          .
09/27/2017  04:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/10/2016  02:10 PM    <DIR>          3Dconnexion
06/11/2016  06:06 PM    <DIR>          ActiveSync
09/27/2017  02:00 AM    <DIR>          Adobe
08/05/2016  04:37 PM    <DIR>          Amazon
11/10/2014  04:53 PM    <DIR>          Apple
11/10/2014  04:54 PM    <DIR>          Apple Computer
09/27/2017  05:32 PM    <DIR>          Apps
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  457,199,636,480 bytes free

f:\mirrors\1day\ENOUGH\Users\dave\AppData\Local>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why del and rmdir don't work as expected, but this does delete the folders that I couldn't otherwise delete:

```
powershell "rd -r \"Apple Computer\""
```

Comment: You wanted to delete APPS directory, and you are deleting "apple computer"direcotry, so maybe thats why it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your command, with `del /f /s /q` the subfolders weren't deleted, only the files in it. I assume there still are subfolders in your case, please do a `dir Apps` after the deletion to verify.

To solve your request you could run this:

```
del /f /s /q Apps
rmdir /s /q Apps
```

Comment: If you read the question, you'll see I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Ah true, you're right, I didn't saw that, I thought I read it exactly ;(. What does a `dir Apps` give you after the `del /f /s /q Apps`?